# Prove that $\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} (1+xy)^\frac{2}{x^2+xy} = e^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Prove that $$\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} (1+xy)^{\frac{2}{x^2+xy}} = e^2.$$

Can someone suggest me the way to prove it? I tried but couldn't get through the $\frac{2}{x^2+xy}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} (1+xy)^{\frac{2}{x^2+xy}} = \lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} e^{\frac{2}{x^2+xy} \ln (1+xy)}$$ $$\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} {\frac{2}{x^2+xy} \ln (1+xy)}=\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} \frac{2xy}{x(x+y)} \frac{ \ln (1+xy)}{xy}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$ (g(x))^{f(x)} = e^{f(x)\ \text{ln} \ g(x)} $$

This is a general strategy that you can try if you encounter difficult exponents when trying to take limits.

(in general you may need to check that the domain of the logarithm is being respected when using this trick - perhaps you can convince yourself that this is allowed here?)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,2)} (1+xy)^{\frac{2}{x^2+xy}} = \lim_{x \to 0} (1+2x)^{\frac{2}{x^2+2x}} =  \lim_{x \to 0} \left((1+2x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^{\frac{2}{x+2}} = e^2
$$

Comment: I thought we can only replace $y=2$ if it is $\lim_{x\to 0}({\lim_{y\to2}}...)$?

Comment: Vinh Quang Tran yes you are correct, although it depends on how the question is asked. If you already know that the limit exists, then you are allowed to approach $(0,2)$ along any path in the $(x,y)$ plane, which includes the path where $y=2$ and so everything is fine. However, if you are not allowed to assume that the limit exists, then this method is incorrect, because it does not show that the limit is $e^2$ independent of path.